# EF Core Migrations Fail when executed in same upgrade

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Sorry about the title I am not sure what to call this.

I have a situation where I need to migrate data from one table to another table after creating the new table.
So I have created two migrations, one for creating the tables generated via the standard Code First shenanigans, and a second migration that does some more complex data porting i.e. calling the MigrationBuilder.Sql("...") with some custom sql.

The problem that I am having is that if I run my project in one go I get an Invalid column exception when ef is trying to apply the migrations, however if I checkout the branch such that I am executing only the first migration (and run the project), then move the branch to include the second migration (and then run the project again) it will happily run the migrations. 
It kinda of feels like there is GO statement missing between the migrations. *I tried to introduce that and it still failed.* Is there away to kind of separate the migrations so that it won't "batch" them but run them one after the other.

Comment: What _GO_ statement did you try? Ever tried `DbContext.Save()`?

Comment: If you write a single SQL script to create a table and insert data you would put a GO statement between the two parts otherwise the script will fail because it does not recognize the the new table/columns. It seems like the migration builder dumps the entire script together without separating the migrations leading them to fail. DbContext.Save doesn't help here because it is being done via the Migration system. Unless you are able to call it which opens up another series of questions.

Comment: @bricelam Does migrations add Go between each migration?

Answer (score 0):

I would think these migrations are already run one at a time, e.g. looking at the effect of changing the order of `migrationBuilder.RenameTable` and  migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey` [mentioned here](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/net/visual-studio-and-entity-framework/multiple-migrations).
So maybe this this is an old bug or feature that got fixed?  I'll give you some options anyway, maybe it's useful to someone.

In incidental cases, you could run the migrations one by one from command-line by calling them by name.  This seems difficult to automate in a build process though.

```
Update-Database -Migration 20190402070159_Migration1
Update-Database -Migration 20190402080259_Migration2
```

You could also run the migrations one by one from code, I would (also) expect that to be different transactions.  (Note, however, calling migrations at runtime is [discouraged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/#apply-migrations-at-runtime), unless "for apps with a local database". Perhaps it risks starting multiple runtime migrations at the same time, with concurrency issues?)
E.g. [stolen form Brice Lam](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7360#issuecomment-275806713):

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    db.Database.OpenConnection();
    try
    {
        var migrator = db.GetService<IMigrator>();
        foreach (var migration in db.Database.GetPendingMigrations())
        {
            migrator.Migrate(migration);
            // I don't expect you need a `db.Save` here
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        db.Database.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```